# I can't close the Excel application

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have this code I wrote in VBScript for wincc, and after running it the Excel application is still running, and the project is not working properly after this script. What can I do to close the Excel app?

Here is the script:

```
Dim fso
Dim rowcount
Dim ExcelObject
Dim WorkbookObject
Dim file
Dim i
Dim tg
Dim objSheet1
Dim objSheet2

'Set Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

file="C:\Parametri\Codificari.xls"
Set WorkbookObject = ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open(file)
'Set objSheet1 = WorkbookObject.Worksheets(1)
Set objSheet2 = WorkbookObject.Worksheets(2)
objSheet2.Cells(1,1)=SmartTags("locatie_defect")

If (fso.FileExists(file)) Then
  'Raw numbering in Excel
  rowcount = objSheet2.UsedRange.Rows.count

  For i=3 To rowcount
    tg="defect_"&i-2
    SmartTags(tg)=objSheet2.Cells(i,2)
  Next
End If

On Error Resume Next

'Save and close excel
ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelObject.Workbooks.Close False 
ExcelObject.Workbooks.Save
ExcelObject.Quit

On Error Resume Next
```

Comment: Maybe surrounding problematic code with `On Error Resume Next` isn't the best idea.

Comment: `ExcelObject.Workbooks.Close False | ExcelObject.Workbooks.SAVE` is contradictory. Try setting `excelobject = nothing`?

Comment: When you read your code, try to do so with the outlook that what you're doing has to make sense. You can't save the `Workbook` after you've closed the `Workbook`, clearly, any more than you can step through a doorway after you've closed the door; it's already closed. You also need to set the `ExcelObject` variable to `Nothing` after you quit, to release the reference, which should allow the Excel application to stop running.

Answer (score 3):

1. The standard way to close (sans error handling)

   ```
   WorkbookObject.Save
   WorkbookObject.Close False
   ExcelObject.Quit
   Set WorkbookObject= Nothing
   Set ExcelObject = Nothing
   ```
2. Ensure all references are fully qualified, see [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/xl_doesnt_quit/). On a quick look-over this doesnt jump out from your code.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Excel doesn't follow COM rules when used as an app object. No doubt for some compatibility reason.

It does follow COM rules as a doc object.

So `Set WorkbookObject = GetObject("C:\Parametri\Codificari.xls")` and now when it goes out of scope it will close as long as it's not visible. So just save it and it will close when your script ends. You probably only need half the lines you have.